# My Junit5 Test class not running, package XXX does not exist error

Tags: java, junit, vert.x

I have a maven project setup as normal:
src/main/java/a/b/c/MyApp
src/test/java/a/b/c/MyAppTest

I am having a weird problem in IntelliJ, where my junit5 test class cannot see the classes in src/main/java/a/b/c/

I get the following error when I run the test class:

```
java: package org.apache.solr.client.solrj does not exist
```

Some of the classes are dependencies.
The mvn clean package works and the Vertx service builds ok and works as expected.

I dont think think its a Vertx issue, I suspect its some basic junit setup issue in Intellij.

Please, any ideas what the issue might be?

Comment: That package sure won't be in src/main/java/a/b/c, it must be in a dependency. You probably need to post your project dependencies pom.xml. Try "update maven project" before, maybe you added the dependency and IntelliJ didn't realize yet.

Comment: Hello Daniu. Yes, its a dependency. That dependency is under external lib in Intellij. My mvn clean package works. Interestingly, the first class it complains about i.e. does not exist, is NOT used or imported in the test class being executed.

Comment: Thanks Daniu, its resolved as per post. Thanks your your input.

Answer (score 0):

My local repo was pointing to the wrong path in IntelliJ Build, Execution, Deployment > Maven > Local repository.